# In one postgres query, determine whether two events happened with a certain amount of time for any individual user

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to find events that occur too close in time to one another, and I'm wondering if there's a way to do this with just one query.

Here's the scenario. I have `events` that have a `definition` and that occur for a specific `userid`. Let's say `event 1` should not occur less than a week after `event 2` for any specific user. So I would like to determine whether for any user, if, given that event 1 occurred today, event 2 occurred *for that same user* within a week. Is there a way to do this with a single SQL query? Ideally it would be something like

```
SELECT event_id, userid as use_userid FROM events WHERE definition = 1 and date > current_date 
- interval '1 day' AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events WHERE userid = use_userid 
AND definition = 2 AND date > current_date - interval '7 days') > 0
```

Am I close? I want to find out for which users this would have happened...the rest of the info is less important.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag` to get the definition and date of the previous row where the rows are partitioned by user and ordered in descending date order. Then use a `where` condition to only get the desired rows.

```
select userid
from (
SELECT 
 userid 
,definition curr_def
,lag(definition) over(partition by userid order by date desc) prev_def
,date - coalesce(lag(date) over(partition by userid order by date desc), date) diffrnce
FROM events 
) t
where diffrnce < 7 and curr_def <> coalesce(prev_def,'xxx')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I learned quite a bit from looking at this (partition by, coalesce, lag). But I ran into a few errors (the 'xxx' and comparing interval diffrnce to an integer). Also I think your code is more expansive (and less efficient) than what I need. I need to do the inquiry for a specific pair of definitions (say 1 and 2). You seem to be selecting any and all pairs of events, but I have many events near in time that are permitted.

Answer (score 0):

would this work for  your purpose?

```
    SELECT distinct userid as use_userid 
    FROM events a 
    JOIN events b using(userid)
    WHERE a.definition = 1 and a.date > current_date - interval '1 day' 
      and b.definition = 2 and b.date > current_date - interval '7 days') > 0
```